# How to test open file limit in Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, network-programming, openresty

So i've been having some issues with our live Nginx servers reaching max open file limits in production. I've increased the number but was wondering how do I test reaching that open file limit in a test environment? Any ideas welcome

Secondary question: I believe the open file limit is an arbitrary number, but was not sure what impact increasing this value could have to performance. What is likely to break if too many files are open in Nginx?